# How to save a state of on Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have three activities. A, B and C. I press a button to open the B through `startActivity(intent)`. From the B I pass data back to A through `intent.putExtra()` and then, from A I get the data through `getIntent`. I'm putting this data in a String on my A. 
The problem is that when I try to do the same with C. The data that I get from the B disappears. 
My question is: How can I get data from two activities?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pass data from activity B to C via A?

If its that what I understand,then follow the foll steps:

Calling A from B:

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),A.class);
i.putExtra("key","value");
startAtivity(i);
```

Fetching data from intent in class A:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String value=extras.getString("key");
```

Passing same data to activity C from class A:

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),C.class);
i.putExtra("key",value);
startAtivity(i);
```

Comment: No, I sorry for the mistake. I wan no clear. I want to pass data from B and C to A. I want to pass data from B to A and from C to A. I can get data from B, but when I get data from C the data that I got before, disappears.

Comment: I just want to now how to receive data from 2 activities diferents.

Comment: I did it!!!!!! Its just need to use the startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult.